# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_default_company'

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, openerp-8

```
class Sale(osv.osv):
_name = 'sale'

_columns = {
    'name': fields.char('Company Name', size=128)
}

def get_default_company(self, cr, uid, context=None):
    company_id = self.pool.get('res.users').browse(cr, uid, uid).company_id.id,
    return company_id
Sale()
```

I used above code , all is well but I don't know where and how to call my function `get_default_company()`. As when I call this method it's give

```
cr and uid invalids
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It look like you need to set default value for your company. for that you need to use `_defaults` model attribute which sets default value for your field. like

```
_defaults = {
    'company_id': get_company
}
```

before this method you need to define get_company method which should return company id like

```
def get_company(self, cr, uid, context=None):
    user_rec = self.pool.get('res.users').browse(cr, uid, uid, context)
    return user_rec.company_id.id
```

and to all this you need a field in `_columns`. so you also need to add `company_id` as `many2one` field. like

```
_columns = {
    'name': fields.char('Company Name', size=128),
    'company_id': fields.many2one('res.company', "Company")
}
```

Alter all this your model will look like,

```
class sale(osv.osv):
    _name = 'sale'

    _columns = {
        'name': fields.char('Company Name', size=128),
        'company_id': fields.many2one('res.company', "Company")
    }


    def get_company(self, cr, uid, context=None):
        user_rec = self.pool.get('res.users').browse(cr, uid, uid, context)
        return user_rec.company_id.id

    _defaults = {
        'company_id': get_company
    }

sale()
```

Hope This helps!

Answer (score 1):

### What is AttributeError: 'NoneType'?

> **NoneType** means that function or instance of whatever **Class** or **Object** not working with you, you've actually got **None**.

---

You are **Sale()** that's why this error occur, you need to call **`get_default_company()`** function, and **calling this function** before you must **implement this method**. otherwise give you error (**get_default_company** **function** does **not exist**).

```
class Sale(osv.osv): 
    _name = 'sale'

    def get_default_company(self, cr, uid, context=None):
        company_id = self.pool.get('res.users').browse(cr, uid, uid).company_id.id,
        return company_id

    get_default_company()             // Call this function

    _columns = {
         'name': fields.char('Company Name', size=128)
    }
```

And you want to create function field yes you can create check this **[documentation](https://doc.openerp.com/trunk/server/03_module_dev_02/#functional-fields)**.

Answer (score 1):

Just add in Sale class _defaults dict. OpenERP will call it automaticly at creating new object.

```
_defaults = {
        'company_id': get_default_company,
}
```

For example look [at here](https://www.openerp.com/files/memento/older_versions/OpenERP_Technical_Memento_v0.6.1.pdf).
More details you can find in OpenERP modules code.